# iPhone SDK Nested For Loop performance

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I have a NSArray of string id and a NSDictionary of NSDictionary objects. I am currently looping through the string id array to match the id value in the NSDictionary.

There are around 200 NSDictionary objects and only 5 or so string ID.

My current code is such:

```
for (NSString *Str in aArr) {
        for (NSDictionary *a in apArr)
        {
            if ([a objectForKey:@"id"] == Str)
            {
            NSLog(@"Found!");
            }
        }
}
```

The performance of the above code is really slow and I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd implement your code in the following way:

```
for (NSDictionary *a in apArr)
{
    if ([aArr containsObject:[a objectForKey:@"id"]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Found!");
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure about containsObject performance, but, I guess there should be SDK optimizations to find objects faster than O(n).

**Added:**

Another suggestion. I suppose, that "id" field is unique for all NSDictionary objects. If it is so, you can remap your NSArray of NSDictionaries to NSDictionary:

from:

index -> NSDictionary

to:

id -> NSDictionary

And you will find elements for O(1) instead of O(n).

**Re remapping.** Either you should create NSDictionary with appropriate format (id -> object) or you may remap your array in the following way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *md = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for ( NSDicationary *a in apArr ) {
    [md setObject:a forKey:[a objectForKey:@"id"]];
}
```

Comment: how would i go about remapping it?

Comment: The documentation for `containsObject:` pretty much says that it is O(n): "This method determines whether anObject is present in the receiver by sending an isEqual: message to each of the receiver’s objects"

Comment: in that case would containsObject on a NSSet be quicker? http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html

Comment: Further info: NSSet method containsObject: operates in O(1) time when applied to a set, while containsObject: operates in O(N) time when applied to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the iPhone's cache architecture, but swapping the two loops so that you make as many lookups on the *same* dictionary before switching to another sounds like it should improve locality. Better locality often leads to (sometimes dramatically) better performance.